# SQLGrammarException and TransactionRequiredException in postgresql with spring data jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm implementing statement deletion from postgresql db table logic in java. But I'm constantly getting various errors.

In general my query looks like this.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "WITH deleted AS (DELETE FROM generated_statements WHERE created_date < :expiryDate RETURNING id) " +
        "SELECT count(*) FROM deleted;", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

But I get `Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

If I remove the `@Modifying` annotation, I get: `could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

I believe the problem is with incorrect annotations. Should I add `@Transactional`? What should I do with my current annotation?

Comment: you should add @Transactional on the method/class from where you are calling this repository function

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Transactional annotation, this way spring / jpa will handle a few things for you: this is opening a new transaction, run your sql query, and commit this transaction.

This is need to overcome potential issues with corrupted data when updating / deleting / modyfing data in any way.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you need a transaction. 
So add `@Transactional`.

As the other error message says: `@Modifying` can not return a `ResultSet`.
Therefore remove the `@Modifying` although it is counter intuitive.

Now I'm still not sure if this does work, but if it doesn't you won't be able to use `@Query` for this at all and should fall back on a custom method implementation based on an injected `JdbcTemplate` or maybe an `EntityManager`.

Comment: I got this `could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` error after removing @Modifying annotation

Comment: As I wrote in the answer: The fallback is to write a custom method.